# Is there a Spotify repository that works for 12.04?

Tags: package-management, music, repository, spotify

The Spotify repository (`deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free`) doesn't work on Ubuntu 12.04 (download failed). Does anyone have a solution to install Spotify on Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 4):

Here's what worked for me:

```
echo "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4E9CFF4E

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

Can you ping the repository?

```
$ ping repository.spotify.com

PING repository.spotify.com (78.31.8.20) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from judith.lon.spotify.com (78.31.8.20): icmp_req=1 ttl=58 time=189 ms
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a new key. Use `94558F59` instead of `4E9CFF4E`.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59
```

Answer (score 2):

I presume your problem is/was the same that I had. That is you went and used the GUI tools for adding the repository. It won't work. It will automatically create a deb-src entry for the repo and they don't, obviously, provide one. Hence you get errors like this (depending on your language of course):

```
W: Tiedoston http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/InRelease nouto ei onnistunut  
Unable to find expected entry 'non-free/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

The simple solution is to:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and delete the deb-src spotify entry.

Then `apt-get update` should succeed and you can proceed to actually installing the Spotify client.

Answer (score 1):

It must be done in terminal as root. You can get in Ubuntu 11.10 and newer, by `sudo -i`. Then follow this steps:

1. Open terminal and enter `sudo -i`
2. Add the following line to your list of repositories by editing your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file using gedit (`gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`)  and save it.

   `deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free`
3. If you want to verify the downloaded packages, you will need to add our public key:

   `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59`
4. Run `sudo apt-get update`
5. Install spotify!

   `sudo apt-get install spotify-client`

[SOURCE](https://www.spotify.com/us/download/previews/)